# Order of a zero of a complex polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a quick and easy way to determine an order of a zero $z_0$ of a complex polynomial without having to derive it $n$ times and check if $\;f^{(n)}(z_0)=0$ or not, which requires a lot of arithmetical routine?

Comment: Differentiating polynomials is as easy as it gets.

Comment: @Timbuc not differentiating, but inserting zeros into them, especially when $\Im(z_0)\not=0$

Comment: Would a numerical estimate suffice?

Comment: @AntonioVargas sorry I don't understand what you mean under numerical estimate

Comment: For example, if $f$ has a zero $z_0$ with multiplicity $n$ then $$\frac{\log f(z)}{\log (z-z_0)} \approx n$$ when $z \approx z_0$.  Would this suffice?  Or are you interested in something more exact?

Comment: There is the argument principle if you'd rather do integrals...

Comment: @AntonioVargas I recall reading in some book (however I don't exactly remember in which one) that there's a interrelation between the grade of the polynom and the grade of its zeros (it just stated this correlation as well as it said "this is how the grade of a zero of a polynom can be easily determined")

Comment: If the polynomial has degree $m$ and a zero of multiplicity $n$ then $n \leq m$, and that's all you can say.

Answer (score 0):

You can always expand into a Laurent series using long division and check the order of the poles of $\frac{1}{f(z)}$. For example, if:

$$f(z)=(z+1)(z-2)^2$$

then the corresponding Laurent expansion of $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ gives:

$$\frac{1}{f(z)}=\frac{1}{(z-2)^2}-\frac{1}{9(z-2)}+\frac{1}{27}-\frac{1}{81}(z-2)+stuff$$

which shows immediately that the order of the zero $z_0=2$ in $f(z)$ is the same as the order of the corresponding pole in $\frac{1}{f(z)}$, that is, 2.

Comment: Is calculating the Laurent expansion of $1/f$ easier than calculating the Taylor expansion of $f$?

Comment: @Antonio Vargas: In the case of the example I gave, for $f(z)=(z+1)(z-2)^2$ the Taylor series is probably easier, as it is only $3(z-2)^2+(z-2)^3$, so you can tell the order is 2. In more general cases, where the polynom may not be nicely factored, I don't know.

Comment: ioannis, I was asking about an easier way to find a grade of a zero of $P(x)$ exactly with the motivation to determine the grade of the pole of ${f(x) \over P(x)}$ and not vice versa :) I should have written it in my question though

Comment: @Dmitry: No problem. In this case, I think Antonio is right, that's why he gave this comment, probably as a wake-up hint: Fishing out the leading term from the Taylor series looks a little easier than fishing out the leading term of the Laurent for $1/f$, particularly since the Taylor expansion of any polynomial has a finite number of terms.